# Checking if value changed - Objective-C Mac OSX

Tags: objective-c, macos, nstimer

```
theTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.00 target:self selector:@selector(sendMessageHandler:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////

- (void)sendMessageHandler (NSTimer *) timer {

}
```

Ok so sendMessageHandler is triggering every second. But now, I want it to check the value of "theString" and if it changed value from the previous run, do something.

Can someone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Great article...really shows my problem, yes. Sorry I'm posting 1000 questions, but this is my first really HUGE app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make another string called prevString.

Make them equal each other initially. Then in the timer:

```
if ([theString isEqualToString:prevString]) {
    //No change.
}
else {
    //Change happened.
    prevString = theString;
}
```

And for memory management in dealloc:

```
[theString release];
[prevString release];
```

Comment: You have it wrong. You must release the old value of `prevString` before assigning the new value, and you must retain the new value (via `[theString copy]`. Otherwise it will leak or overrelease.